# write into Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a Hbase table: 'employeedetails' with column families: 'personaldetails','professionaldetails'

When I try to write using put for multiple column families, like below:

```
put 'employeedetails','1','personaldetails:firstname','Steven','personaldetails:lastname','Gerrard','professionaldetails:company','ABC','professionaldetails:empid','123abc'
```

I get the error message:

```
ERROR: wrong number of arguments (10 for 6)
Here is some help for this command:
Put a cell 'value' at specified table/row/column and optionally
timestamp coordinates.  To put a cell value into table 'ns1:t1' or 't1'
at row 'r1' under column 'c1' marked with the time 'ts1', do:
```

But if I put the data into ColumnFamily's columns one by one, it works.

```
hbase(main):040:0> put 'employeedetails','1','personaldetails:firstname','Steven'
0 row(s) in 0.0190 seconds
```

Can anyone tell me if I am doing any mistake while writing for multiple column families or is there any difference in the concept of writing multiple column families in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hbase, you cannot write multiple column qualifiers in one go.

Put is meant for writing a single cell value into the Hbase table.

> Put a cell ‘value’ at specified table/row/column and optionally
>   timestamp coordinates.

Split your `put` statement into multiple individual `put` statements.